# Remote Repo in Artifactory doesn't find any artefacts

Tags: artifactory

I defined an Artifactory Remote Repository with following URL:

https://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/maven2repository/

There are definitely artifacts.

When I configure a remote repository:

[image]

this repository is empty.

When I open my new repository, it is empty:

[image]

but I expect this content:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the same remote URL without the trialing slash at the end and it worked. Try removing the slash at the end and refresh the repository to see if the remote artifacts are reflecting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: I discovered later, that you cannot always browse the remote repository directly, but if I configure a dependency from there, it works!

THANK YOU <3

Comment: Yes correct, not all the remote registry supports "listing of contents". So, unless the artifacts are resolved, it would not be listed in the Artifactory's repository in such cases.